# How to save a BufferedImage that is generated by Potrace after vectorization in a file with svg format?

Tags: java, svg, vector-graphics, image-transcoding

I am using PotraceJ ([potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net) library's java version) - note that potrace is used for vectorization of images.

Situation - potrace traces image, and stores the result in a BufferedImage, which is then displayed in a JPanel as an ImageIcon.

My problem - I want to save this BufferedImage instead as a file say vector.svg 
Using ImageIO.write() I tried but **no file is created when I do that.** Possible reason could be Java's image writers may not write svg

I have to store this vectorized image as an svg file. How should I do that?

The code that mainly vectorzies a raster image is embeded here. While you can find the whole library here at [github](https://github.com/sannysanoff/potracej).

```
            package potracej.src;

            import potracej.src.compat.ConvertToJavaCurves;
            import potracej.src.compat.PathElement;
            import potracej.src.potracej.Bitmap;
            import potracej.src.potracej.PoTraceJ;
            import potracej.src.potracej.param_t;
            import potracej.src.potracej.path_t;

            import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
            import javax.swing.*;
            import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
            import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
            import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
            import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
            import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
            import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
            import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.nio.file.Path;
            import java.nio.file.Paths;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashSet;

            /**
             * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
             * User: san
             * Date: 6/10/12
             * Time: 12:55 PM
             * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
             */
            public class Main {

                static BufferedImage result;
                static Bitmap bmp;
                static param_t param = new param_t();
                static double scale = 1;
                static ImageIcon resultIcon;
                static ImageIcon srcIcon;
                static BufferedImage sourceImage;
                static boolean renderSourceImage = false;

                public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                    Path p = Paths.get(new File(".").getCanonicalPath()+"/potracej/girl.png");
                    sourceImage = ImageIO.read(p.toFile());

                    //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                    WritableRaster raster = sourceImage.getRaster();
                    int[] iarr = new int[4];
                    bmp = new Bitmap((int)(sourceImage.getWidth()), (int)(sourceImage.getHeight()));
                    for(int y=0; y<sourceImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                        for(int x=0; x<sourceImage.getWidth(); x++) {
                            int[] pixel = raster.getPixel(x, y, iarr);
                            if (pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2] + pixel[3] != 0) {
                                bmp.put(x, y, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    BufferedImage d2 = new BufferedImage((int) (scale * sourceImage.getWidth()), (int)(scale * sourceImage.getHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics2D d2g = (Graphics2D) d2.getGraphics();
                    d2g.scale(scale, scale);
                    d2g.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
                    d2g.dispose();
                    sourceImage.flush();
                    srcIcon = new ImageIcon(d2);

                    doTrace(scale);

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Result") {
                        {
                            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                            resultIcon = new ImageIcon(result, "Result");
                            JButton resultButton = new JButton(resultIcon);
                            resultButton.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
                                @Override
                                protected void paintButtonPressed(Graphics g, AbstractButton b) {
                                    //
                                }
                            });
                            add(resultButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            resultButton.setPressedIcon(srcIcon);
                            JPanel stuff = new JPanel();
                            add(stuff, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                            stuff.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
                            stuff.add(new JLabel("Suppress speckles"));
                            final JSlider turdSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, param.turdsize);
                            stuff.add(turdSlider);
                            turdSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                                    param.turdsize = turdSlider.getValue();
                                    doRetrace();
                                }
                            });
                            stuff.add(new JLabel("Smooth corners"));
                            final JSlider smoothSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 300, (int) (param.opttolerance * 100));
                            stuff.add(smoothSlider);
                            smoothSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                                    param.opttolerance = smoothSlider.getValue() / 100.0;
                                    doRetrace();
                                }
                            });
                            stuff.add(new JLabel("Optimize paths"));
                            final JSlider optSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 125, (int) (param.alphamax * 100));
                            stuff.add(optSlider);
                            optSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                                    param.alphamax = optSlider.getValue()/100.0;
                                    doRetrace();
                                }
                            });
                            final JCheckBox renderSource = new JCheckBox("Render source");
                            stuff.add(renderSource);
                            renderSource.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    renderSourceImage = renderSource.getModel().isArmed();
                                    doRetrace();
                                }
                            });

                        }

                        private void doRetrace() {
                            doTrace(scale);

                            resultIcon.setImage(result);
                            repaint();
                        }
                    };
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                }

                private static void doTrace(double scale) {
                    PoTraceJ poTraceJ = new PoTraceJ(param);
                    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    path_t trace = null;
                    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        trace = poTraceJ.trace(bmp);
                        Thread.yield();
                    }
                    poTraceJ.resetTimers();
                    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                        trace = poTraceJ.trace(bmp);
                    }
                    poTraceJ.printTimers();
                    l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;
                    System.out.println("L="+l);
                    ArrayList<PathElement> al = new ArrayList<PathElement>();
                    ConvertToJavaCurves.convert(trace, new HashSet<ConvertToJavaCurves.Point>(), al);

                    if (result != null)
                        result.flush();
                    result = new BufferedImage((int)(scale * bmp.getWidth()), (int)(scale * bmp.getHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)result.getGraphics();
                    g2.scale(scale, scale);
                    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g2.fillRect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
                    for (PathElement pathElement : al) {
                        switch (pathElement.getType()) {
                            case CLOSE_PATH:
                                path.closePath();
                                break;
                            case LINE_TO:
                                path.lineTo(pathElement.getP0x(), pathElement.getP0y());
                                break;
                            case MOVE_TO:
                                path.moveTo(pathElement.getP0x(), pathElement.getP0y());
                                break;
                            case CURVE_TO:
                                path.curveTo(pathElement.getP0x(), pathElement.getP0y(), pathElement.getP1x(), pathElement.getP1y(), pathElement.getP2x(), pathElement.getP2y());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
                    g2.fill(path);
                }

            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert this object:

```
GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
```

to [SVGPath](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/svggen/SVGPath.html) using [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

1. Add dependencies into **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-anim</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Create methods:

```
private static SVGOMDocument createSvgDocument(int width, int height) {
    DOMImplementation domImpl = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
    SVGOMDocument document = (SVGOMDocument) domImpl.createDocument(SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, "svg", null);
    Element svgTag = document.getRootElement();
    svgTag.setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
    svgTag.setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));
    return document;
}

private static void putPathToSvgDocument(SVGOMDocument document, GeneralPath path) {
    SVGGeneratorContext ctx = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(document);
    SVGPath svgPath = new SVGPath(ctx);
    Element svgElement = svgPath.toSVG(path);
    svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "#000");
    document.getRootElement().appendChild(svgElement);
}

private static void saveSvgDocumentToFile(SVGOMDocument document, File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);
    try (Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")) {
        svgGenerator.stream(document.getDocumentElement(), out);
    }
}
```

3. Almost ready. Now we can create SVG file with our GeneralPath inside

```
GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
...
// TODO: set your image width and height ;)
SVGOMDocument document = createSvgDocument(1000,1000);
putPathToSvgDocument(document, path);

// TODO: set your filename :)
saveSvgDocumentToFile(document, new File("c:\\temp\\result.svg"));
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking forward to an answer to this would probably be someone like me. Newbie into image processing and looking for libraries that can quench the thirsts of your expedition. I haven't found solution to this problem and I cannot guide you anyone wrongly that what else can be done.

I observed that **most of the image processing libraries** are written in **C++. Fewer libraries are there in Java. Why? Performance**. And so for anyone who wants to produce efficient code and all the algorithms input be appreciated should use C++ too.

I want above solution for my Android application. I am going to write code in C++ and connect it via Android NDK.

For all other lost souls, be brave and take this decision. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_is_better_for_image_processing_C_or_Java) is my evidence to prove that.